# Failed to launch JVM

Tags: java

I have searched for similar problems on SO but did not find any clues how to resolve this error.

Have developed a small console application (running on windows 10).
Have packaged it into a jar and then deployed it with javapackager.

```
"C:\...\javapackager.exe" -deploy -Bruntime= -native image -Bicon=MedicineCounter.ico -srcdir . -srcfiles MedicineCounter.jar -outdir . -appclass com.fll.Main -name "MedicineCounter" -nosign
```

When running the executable (cmd/explorer) I get:

> Failed to launch JVM

but when running the JAR with java -jar it works fine.
The app has no dependencies except for java itself.

Comment: I know this doesn't help, but I've hit the same problem. I will try to post here if I find a solution.

Comment: Can this [link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8151377) help you?

Comment: @FabrícioPereira That link solved my problem! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8151377) can help you.
There is a bug that was resolved at JDK-9 b172.